# What would be the most efficient way to farm humans?

Tags: agriculture

One day, a type 2 civilization with a taste for unusual meat stumble across earth. They then capture every human being on earth and take them to a planet where they are placed until they are eventually killed off and sold to every supermarket in the galaxy. And the females are also used for there milk which can always be found in aisle three in the dairy section.

What would be the best way to butcher human meat and most efficiently?

Comment: you may want to read "bordered in black" by larry niven. similar premise.

Comment: A terrific short story on this topic (from the point of view of alien foodies) is Kuszib by Hassan Abdulrazzak.  In this anthology: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34759977-iraq-100

Comment: Check out "The Promised Neverland"

Comment: The way we do now, the only real problem is keeping them unaware of harvest time, we used to use wars as cover for our discrete population harvests (the numbers were hidden among war deaths), more recently we've been using Corvid but we'll need a new one soon, 'free range' humans, tastier than factory farmed.

Comment: there are three very different questions here, please pick one.

Answer (score 20):

> a type 2 civilization

These would be people with the ability to make black holes from light ?  Own their own Dyson Swarm and so on ?

Seems very unlikely a type II civilization would need to slaughter actual animals to eat.  It's practically a given they'd be able to *manufacture* meat that was indistinguishable from the real thing.

> I was asking what would be the best way to butcher and collect the meat and most efficiently

Most efficiently ?

Grow your own "steaks" in a factory using advanced biochemistry or cloning technology or some technique.  This avoids the slaughtering problem, the disposal of unwanted bits and the need to worry about breeding animals (always messy and terribly inefficient :-) ).  Likewise milk.

And I'm trying hard to imagine a reason a completely alien species would not find human meat and milk actually dangerous to eat, never mind like it.  And I'm failing.

So no butcher, just a large biochemical plant doing complex things with advanced techniques available to your average Type II civilization.

Comment: Don't be silly. We can make perfectly acceptable veggie burgers that even taste like meat. And you know what, I won't eat them. I want a cow slaughtered to satiate my appetite, and these KII aliens won't be any different.

Comment: Wait I thought type 2 civilizations were the ones that could collect all the available energy on their planets.

Comment: [The Kardashev Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardashev_scale#Type_II_civilization_methods) in all it's glory. :-)  Even type I ought to have developed synthetic meat production methods, particularly with all that energy to play with.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes a lot of sense

Comment: @kingledion The main reason people eat meat instead of artificial products in a combination of habit, normal reluctance to try anything different and price - my experience is that you can get cheap meat but vegetarian alternatives are more expensive.  That's unlikely to be an issue for a Type I or II civilization.

Comment: So where are humans on the scale

Comment: We're not on the original scale, we're below the minimal entry requirement. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71271/discussion-between-bryan-and-stepheng).

Answer (score 11):

Humans are expensive creatures to keep. Slave holding was already dying in hte US when the civil war erupted because it was not economical in the long run.

However, the easy way to farm humans is to leave them in place, then harvest a fixed percentage on a regular basis.

Having never tasted human meat (apart from my own fingers burnt when soldering too inattentively) I would presume that there is a "best age" for the harvesting. Typically, farm animals are harvested as young adults. The ideal venue for harvesting, then, is (drumroll ...) high school.  Lure the "favored" graduates into your slaughterhouse with the right incentives and then the rest is much like any cattle slaughter operation.

Comment: But I find it strange that you have never eaten human

Comment: Not that I'll admit to anyways.

Comment: Well I’m starting a humanitarian diet we’re I eat only human meats

Comment: Please take the ball team and cheerleaders first.

Comment: @Bryan I agree. I find it very strange as well, as I too am a humanitarian and can't see any arguments against it.

Comment: Humans, in addition to being expensive, are dangerous to eat when we're too old.  We accumulate toxic metals like any other apex predator.

Answer (score 11):

## Harvest after a growth spurt

Here is a graph of human mass gain by year.

[image]

There seem to be two best times. Either harvest after the steady childhood development phase, at age 6-8; or harvest after the adolescent growth sport finishes around age 15 for females and 18 for males.

However, humans waste a lot of time and energy developing big brains. If you are really a Kardashev II civilization, you might do better breeding something that grows faster for the taste you want. Assuming that there is something in primate genetics that tastes good, a gorilla might be a better bet. They will grow to ~70 kg for a female and ~135kg for a male in only 10 years; plus they are easier to feed on a cheap, all-vegetation diet.

Also, you are going to hell for making me think about eating 6 year old children. Teenagers are fine though, no one would miss them.

Comment: Kingledion, the aliens want a lot more meat and the population of gorillas is very low. I guess it would be very plausible that they could clone the gorillas but this was sadly not the answer I was looking fir

Comment: Kingledion I’m technically a teenager

Comment: @Bryan Yum.....

Comment: Well in about 6 months I’ll turn 20 so

Comment: @Kingledion:   Cloning could solve that problem, making it unnecessary to kill even a single wild gorilla.  Reproductive gorilla cloning would allow the aliens to sample every edible part of a gorilla's body.  Selective organ cloning would allow the most desirable gorilla parts to be grown in tanks.

Comment: This isn't a plot of mass over time.  It's a plot of height over time.  But plus one for "Teenagers are fine though, no one would miss them."

Answer (score 7):

Don't take all the humans - take a subset (kidnap babies, or even kidnap humans, harvest eggs and sperm and create a first, clean slate generation) , bring them elsewhere and and create a primitive society. Have periodic sacrifices to the gods with humans or milk.

Unlike most livestock, you can probably get them to grow their own food and feed themselves and just periodically skim your product off the top.

Modern humans are too likely to rebel and you don't really *need* to ship humanity elsewhere. I'd actually suggest *protecting* your market by keeping *other* races away from earth, and keeping the humans from going too far away, while you run your primitive human farms.

Comment: *Modern humans are too likely to rebel* I guess it will only take a few generations of selective breeding to eliminate that behavior: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domesticated_red_fox.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, humans aren't very "cooperative" when it comes to being farmed. As such, traditional farms would be *immensely* inefficient.

With that in mind, I suggest more of a "free-range" approach. Here's the rough steps:

1. Find a suitable population of humans.
2. Reduce them to a stone-age technological level, provided that they aren't already there.
3. Gradually "harvest" humans at a rate slightly below the reproduction rate (to account for natural deaths).

There's one catch. Assuming an average reproduction rate of 1.25 (2.5 per female) over a 35 year average life expectancy, the rough doubling rate is 120 years. With some slight jiggering to account for natural deaths, sustainable harvesting rates are on the order of "half the population every 130 years," which is quite low for a meat animal. In other words: **You're going to need a *huge* population for this to work.**

Answer (score 3):

**What would be the best way to butcher human meat and most efficiently or what would be the most efficient way to farm humans?**

These are two completely different questions

Free-range humans is the easiest.

1. Leave the humans on Earth.
2. Start "Move to a new planet Corp LTD"
3. Offer free land grants for new settlers on a planet 1500 light years away
4. Pop your willing settlers in their cryochambers / the snack freezer
5. Profit

People will leave expecting to never return and they'll bring their whole families or just themselves if they have no-one.

This will leave more room on Earth for more humans to breed, your snacks will freeze themselves and there is no communication with a planet so far away so nobody will notice for thousands of years that they're even missing.

Just imagine the poor of China, Africa or India that have no land and no future. You'll have huge waiting lists to fill your snack cupboards up.

Health checks and immigration rules means the beef will grade itself.

It's food that farms itself.....

Answer (score 1):

The question of **efficiently** harvesting humans for a type II civilization is somewhat strange since, at least I, would not expect such a civilization to be bothered that much with efficiency.

That being said, one of the most efficient ways would be to keep them (us) like cattle. Keep them indoor and separately or in small groups and add mind numbing and reproductive drugs to the water supply and put them on a high fat diet or what the alien prefer. Without group interaction and after some generation you can breed preferable qualities, docility, etc. The **efficient** butchering can be done per group the same as cattle.

A little bit more technology minded would be to use the same method as shown in the matrix. Just keep the humans asleep in the pods and add the appropriate nutrients. Depending on the civilization this might be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Type II civilization uses social engineering.

Perhaps changing our society to be like Logan's Run, so everybody who turns a certain age (determined by testing for us to be highly flavorful) turns themselves into the church to be enlightened, and never more to be seen by living humans. The actual butchering is hidden from us.

Or maybe we each have an implant designed to show when we are most flavorful.

At any rate, I would separate human society into different regions/cities such that each one thinks they are the only one.

It's better to have contented cows, er... human meat organisms.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is fairly simple like dogs. In the early days we selected for traits that were desirable in the species. I.e. cute, loyal, etc. We just need to do the same thing with humans. So what records are we looking for? Accelerated maturity. Take a look at the youngest natural births. Some of those kids were as young as 6 or 7. This gives us a goal and test subject. Next we need to know how to increase muscle and fat production. That is simple. There's two copies of a gene that restricts the amount of muscle on individual for lean beef specifically. For fat it'll call for a high carb diet. For penning then in, put them on an earth with slightly more gravity or a solar system to far away for them to reach another easily. Alternatively you could breed intelligence out of them but that would drive profits way down.